# Use the Datetimeoffset (Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) on C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, utc

I'm trying to use UTC with .NET and SQL Server 2019.

I want to obtain the files expired between two dates, on .net i am using this code to obtain UTC:`new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(utcNow.Year, utcNow.Month, utcNow.Day, 0, 0, 0));`

- begindate "12/06/2022 00:00:00 +01:00"
- endDate"12/06/2022 00:00:00 +01:00"

On SQL Server I have the field expirationDate set to `datetimeoffset(7)`.

example: 2020-07-30 23:00:00.0000000 +00:00.

When I try to execute the query, I get this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The query generated contains this line: `ExpirationDate >= '23/06/2022 00:00:00 +01:00' AND ExpirationDate < '29/06/2022 00:00:00 +01:00` and I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

If I change the line to this: `ExpirationDate >= '06/23/2022 00:00:00 +01:00' AND ExpirationDate < '12/29/2022 00:00:00 +01:00`, it works and i get results.

In conclusion, if I switch the field "month" to "day" and the field "day" to "month" it works. What should I do on the .NET to send the date correctly to SQL?

Below, I show the code I used on .NET:

[image]

Query SQL:

[image]

```
Select Distinct

    [DefaultLanguage],
    [Email],
    [SupplierCompanyId]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SupplierQualification.Id, [File].FileTypeId ORDER BY [File].ExpirationDate DESC) RowNumber,
        [File].ExpirationDate,
        Companies.DefaultLanguage,
        Companies.Email,
        SupplierQualification.CompanyId [SupplierCompanyId]
    FROM
        Reply
    INNER JOIN
        FormReply
    ON  FormReply.Id = Reply.FormReplyId
    INNER JOIN
        SupplierQualification
    ON  SupplierQualification.Id = FormReply.SupplierQualificationId
    INNER JOIN
        AttachmentQuestion
    ON  AttachmentQuestion.QuestionId = Reply.QuestionId
    INNER JOIN
        [File]
    ON  [File].FileTypeId = AttachmentQuestion.FileTypeId AND
        [File].CompanyId = SupplierQualification.CompanyId
    INNER JOIN
        FileType
    ON  FileType.Id = [File].FileTypeId
    INNER JOIN
        Companies
    ON  Companies.CompanyID = SupplierQualification.CompanyId
)   AttachedFile
WHERE
    AttachedFile.RowNumber = 1 AND
ExpirationDate >= '12/06/2022 00:00:00 +01:00' AND ExpirationDate < '13/06/2022 00:00:00 +01:00'ORDER BY 1
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Database

expirationDate - datetimeoffset(7)

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not passing these value as proper parameters? Injecting data is a big security risk, and can cause errors as you have seen. Datetime values don't have "formats" they are binary values, and when you pass them as parameters they stay that way

Comment: "Is there any reason you are not passing these value as proper parameters? Injecting data is a big security risk, and can cause errors as you have seen." This  is old code, it i need to use.

Comment: The error i get in the console application ' Error Number:241,State:1,Class:16
      Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)'

Comment: Well `'12/06/2022 00:00:00 +01:00'` doesn't look very easy to convert: the server won't know if it's `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`, you should instead use an unambiguous date format such as `yyyymmdd hh:MM:ss zzz` see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5206/sql-server-datetime-best-practices/?utm_source=AaronBertrand. This is one reason you should always parameterize your queries: it improves correctness not just security. [It is fairly trivial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters) to do so, I don't think you should let "old code" get in your way